# I'm getting an error when using Swagger's $ref for pathsCould not resolve reference: Tried to resolve a relative URL, without having a basePath

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

So, I am trying to create api documentation using Swagger, however, I'm trying to avoid a giant yaml file for all of our calls. Here is what I'm trying to do:

**server.js**

```js
const swaggerOptions = {
  swaggerDefinition: {
    openapi: '3.0.0',
    info: {
      title: "API",
      version: "1.0.0",
      description: "The API",
      contact: {
        name: "name"
      },
    },
    servers: [
      {
        url: "http://localhost:5000/api/"
      },
    ],
  },
  basePath: "/",
  apis: [
    "./swagger/main.yaml",
  ]
};

const swaggerDocs = swaggerJSDoc(swaggerOptions);
app.use("/api-docs", swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocs));
```

**main.yaml**

```yaml
components:
  securitySchemes:
    ApiKeyAuth:
      type: apiKey
      in: header
      name: apikey
paths:
  /user:
    $ref: "user.yaml" #<-- I've tried many different variations of this path but none of them worked
```

**user.yaml**

```yaml
get:
  summary: "Get user by ID"
  parameters:
    - in: query
      name: id
      required: true
      schema:
        type: integer
  responses:
    "200":
      description: "Successful response"
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              id:
                type: integer
              name:
                type: string
  security:
    - ApiKeyAuth: []
```

I've tried many different variations of the path to the file, but none of them worked. I keep getting the error: `Could not resolve reference: Tried to resolve a relative URL, without having a basePath. path: 'user.yaml' basePath: 'undefined'`

According to [their documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/) for using `$ref`, this seems like it's possible.

I'm just trying to have everything organized and to avoid a giant yaml file for all my api calls.

Comment: See if this helps: https://github.com/scottie1984/swagger-ui-express/issues/69